# Routing to the localhost, how does it work?

Tags: networking, route

The output of  `/sbin/route -n` on my Linux box doesn't mention the **127.x.x.x** address range, neither it mentions **lo** interface. Nevertheless `ping localhost` and `ssh localhost` are working fine.

How the computer knows the route to **127.0.0.1** if it's not in the routing table?

Comment: `cat /etc/hosts`

Comment: **/etc/hosts** defines mapping from symbolical host name (**localhost** in our case) to its IP address (**127.0.0.1** in our case). Now if you read the question you'll see that your comment ain't relevant.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/683538/why-isnt-there-a-route-for-localhost-in-ubuntu

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's basically the same question, answered.

Comment: @gogoud & ilya, you can copy the answer here (just put a link at the top for where it came from) so that this question has an answer.

Comment: Stackexchange engine decided to "convert a trivial answer into a coment" ;)

Comment: Copy the whole answer, not just a link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*(Copied from https://serverfault.com/a/683542/68920)*

The `route` command is deprecated, and should not be used anymore.

The new way is to use the iproute set of commands, which are all invoked with `ip` followed by an object. For example:

```
$ ip route show
default via 192.168.1.254 dev eth0 
192.168.0.0/23 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.27
```

Now, I hear you say, this is basically the same info! Yes, but this isn't the whole story. Before the routing tables (yes, plural) comes the rule table:

```
$ ip rule show
    0:  from all lookup local 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

The routing table we were looking at before is the `main` routing table. Your question concerns the `local` routing table, which contains all routes relating to local connections. This table can be shown as follows:

```
$ ip ro sh table local
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 192.168.0.0 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.27 
local 192.168.1.27 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope host  src 192.168.1.27 
broadcast 192.168.1.255 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.27
```

(You can abbreviate `ip` options / parameters as long as they're still unique, hence `ip ro sh` is the same as `ip route show`.)

Here you can see the loopback routes.

You can do all sorts of wonderful things with this *policy-based routing*, I recommend you read [Policy Routing with Linux](http://www.policyrouting.org/PolicyRoutingBook/) by Matthew G. Marsh for all the info you'll ever need.